# Rotating an image gradually from one degree to another

Tags: java, android, math, android-canvas

This is my first post, so please bear with me. I'll try and be as clear as I can here about my problem. 
First off, let me say that I suck at math. I failed it in school, and it pains me to no end that I can't grasp simple math concepts, especially since I love to code. Someone who wants to program, and can't perform basic math operations? Bad combo. 
Aaaanyway, on to the problem.

Some context. I am writing an asteroids-type game. It's coming along quite nicely, and I've overcome all my hurdles so far thanks to this site (thank you!), and google. I've searched high and low to a solution to my problem, but it always seems like I run into a solution that either doesn't work, or I just don't understand and can't incorporate it into my code.

The issue involves rotation of the ship. I have an onscreen joystick class that returns the angle that the joystick is being pushed. I use that angle to point the ship in that same direction.

What I want to do is *gradually* turn the ship towards the angle the user wants to go, using the shortest turn, left or right. In my mind I'm thinking "How the hell do I go to say.. 350 degrees from 5 degrees, going left?". I don't know...

Here is my draw code:

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas){
    canvas.save();
    canvas.rotate((float) (fAngle + 90), (float) (dX + (mShip.getIntrinsicWidth() / 2)), (float) (dY + (mShip.getIntrinsicHeight() / 2)));
    mShip.setBounds((int)dX, (int)dY, (int)dX + mShip.getIntrinsicWidth(), (int)dY + mShip.getIntrinsicHeight());
    mShip.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

The angle is passed to the fAngle variable from the joystick getangle method. The angle is then increased by 90 degrees because of the image facing.

```
user.fAngle = oJoystick.getAngle();
```

So on each game tick, I want to turn the ship towards whatever direction the player wants to go, degree by degree. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks for reading!

Comment: http://asgamer.com/2009/as3-character-movement-asteroids-style-360-degree-movement - check this out, the author does a great job of explaining the movements he does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your tick function, instead of:
    user.fAngle = oJoystick.getAngle();

Use this (adjust increment to your liking - this controls the rotation speed):

```
const float increment = 1.0;
float direction;
float joy = oJoystick.getAngle();
float ang = user.fAngle;
float fudge = 5.0;

if (abs (joy - ang) > fudge) {
    if (joy > ang) {
        if (joy - ang < 180)
            direction = 1;
        else
            direction = -1;
    } else if (joy < ang) {       
        if (ang - joy < 180)
            direction = -1;
        else
            direction = 1;
    }
} else // already pointing right direction
    direction = 0;

user.fAngle = ang + direction * increment;
if (0 > user.fAngle)
    user.fAngle += 360;
if (360 < user.fAngle)
    user.fAngle -= 360;
```

Comment: This is a HUGE step in the right direction. Thank you! 
Some issues. Sometimes the ship spins out of control. 
And the ship 'shakes' once it's pointed in the right direction. I'm assuming this has something to do with the floats and rounding.

Comment: Not sure about the spinning, but I edited the code to make it shake less. Tweak 'fudge' to your liking.

Comment: The 'fudge' works great, thanks again. Still looking into the ship spinning out of control. I have a thought. Do you think the canvas.rotate((float) (fAngle + 90) in my code is messing with this? I'm half thinking I should get rid of that, fix the image (rotate it in the bitmap itself) and maybe that'll fix it?

Comment: Not sure what to say about the spinning. It's hard for me to debug from here. ;) Seems like maybe the joystick input is a little wonky or something.

Comment: Doing a little debugging here. The user.fAngle goes into negative numbers, which of course totally botches everything.

Comment: Ah ok. Just limit fAngle to 0-360 in the last statement and all should be good. (I updated the code to do this)

Comment: yea, tried that. still no go. All that does is lock the ship to one direction (0, or 359) when things are awry. It's weird, because most of the time it spins left uncontrollably. Sometimes I can get it to spin right uncontrollably. And sometimes, it's just fine! argh!

Comment: Got it! I flubbed up the 0-360 limitation at the end. Here's what I have..
  if (user.fAngle > 359) user.fAngle = 0;
  if (user.fAngle < 0) user.fAngle = 359; It's working perfectly now with that! THANK YOU! I want to give you props, but I need rep I guess.